# How to check if 2 <img> tags contain the same image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a Memory cards game(where cards are flipped on their back and you must open and find the pairs)

I have 12 divs with 12 images and there 6 pairs of images. How can I write JS or jQuery code to check if the images are the same ?

I added data index to divs with `setAttribute` but on `console.log` they print `undefined`.

```
<div class="frontCard">
  <img src="frontCard1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="frontCard">
  <img src="frontCard2.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="frontCard">
  <img src="frontCard1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

and js code

```
const item = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
item.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.setAttribute("data-index", index);

})

var openCards = 0;
var points=0;
$(".card").click(function() {
    if (openCards >= 2) {

        $(".card").removeClass('cardOpen');

        $(this).addClass('cardOpen');
        openCards = 1;

    } else {
        $(this).addClass('cardOpen');
        openCards++;
        if (openCards == 2) {
            if (true)//this is where i need the condition
 {
                const openCard = document.querySelectorAll(".cardOpen");
                console.log("index:" + openCard.index);
                points++;
                console.log(points);
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Please post your js code

Comment: Where's the JS which attempts to do what you need? And also the logic which adds the data attribute, and shows undefined?

Comment: validate the data before its coming to the view

Comment: You could use getAttribute to get the src of the image and compare or count those. I don't understand the use case though. Do the images change or something so that you do not know in advance which image will be inside which `<img>` tag?

Comment: Show us what you tried that isn't working. The objective here is to help you with *your code*, not write it all for you. Also telling us you logged something but not showing that to us is virtually meaningless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically there are multiple things wrong in your js.
First of - shouldn't .card be .frontCard?

I got a code which is working as expected, even though it might not be the most beuatiful.
Check out the snippet

```js
const item = document.querySelectorAll(".frontCard");
item.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.setAttribute("data-index", index);

})

var openCards = 0;
var points=0;
$(".frontCard").click(function() {
    if (openCards >= 2) {
        $(".frontCard").removeClass('cardOpen');
        openCards = 1;
        $(this).addClass('cardOpen');                
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('cardOpen');
        openCards++;
        if (openCards == 2) {        
            if ($($(".cardOpen")[0]).find("img")[0].src == $($(".cardOpen")[1]).find("img")[0].src){
                const openCard = document.querySelectorAll(".cardOpen");
                console.log("index:" + openCard.index);
                points++;
                console.log(points);
                $(".frontCard").removeClass('cardOpen');
            }else{        
             console.log("NoPoints")
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="frontCard">
  <img src="https://seomofo-da30.kxcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/google_logo_new.png" alt="test">
</div>
<div class="frontCard">
  <img src="https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/9013_preview.png" alt="test2">
</div>
<div class="frontCard">
  <img src="https://seomofo-da30.kxcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/google_logo_new.png" alt="test3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your cards are using the same image, you could check against that. This would require adding ID fields to each card in order to compare the individual cards.

A better way to do this would be to write some JavaScript to contain the cards in an array and fill the array with some ints such as [0,0,1,1,2,2...]. You could then use that to shuffle the cards, or display them and check their values. Just leave yourself a comment as to which number corresponds to which card:)

This would also allow you to display them dynamically if you always start with the back image and then replace the element by ID with the appropriate new image (or lay it over top of it to hide it)